# Plugin Jasper repot Jsf null pointer

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jasper-reports

I have a jsf project, I wanted to integrate the plugin jsf jasperreport : [plugin jr-jsf](http://jasperreportjsf.sourceforge.net/web/index.html) ,
The compilation is going well but when I deployed the application , I get the following error. If anyone can help me find and correct the error.
Thank you in advance

```
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) net.sf.jasperreports.jsf.config.ConfigurationStartupListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.jasperreports.jsf.config.XmlHelper.getText(XmlHelper.java:168)
at net.sf.jasperreports.jsf.config.XmlHelper.getChildText(XmlHelper.java:158)
at net.sf.jasperreports.jsf.config.Configuration.loadMappings(Configuration.java:179)
at net.sf.jasperreports.jsf.config.Configuration.loadMappings(Configuration.java:163)
at net.sf.jasperreports.jsf.config.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:114)
at net.sf.jasperreports.jsf.config.ConfigurationStartupListener.contextInitialized(ConfigurationStartupListener.java:60)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1462)
```

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related?

Comment: By adding the jar primefaces ; I work with version 3.5.
The project works before the integration of the plugin jasper -report jsf fact I only have to remove the jars so that it works again.

Comment: I kind of do not fully understand what exactly is the issue. You started with just PrimeFaces. That worked until you added the jr-jsf? In the stacktrace is nothing about PrimeFaces, so it is not PrimeFaces related. Keep in mind that from what I read, jr-jsf is for jsf1.2

Comment: How are you configuring the listener and what JSF version are you running? Post your faces-config.xml here